# How to make image zoom and move to the point click

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a reactive website and in it I have an image I want to move (like on this [page](https://www.sanleonardo.it/en/la-tenuta)) that when clicked on any point the screen will automatically move to that point.

I can't seem to find a good way to do this so I was wondering what is a good way to do this?

Comment: Hey, you can simply do that using "transform" property in CSS. Another way to do this is "requestAnimationFrame" - refer this link for more info: https://agm1984.medium.com/use-react-to-make-a-photo-follow-the-mouse-aka-transform-perspective-or-tilt-7c38f1b3a623

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn't seem right in my case. What I mean is that when you click on a point on the map, the image will move to that point and there will be binoculars at the point you clicked.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by using `transform-origin` and `scale`. Just caculate the x,y coordinate of the point clicked, then add origin base to x,y like `transform-origin: 6.85739% 53.5082%;`